# How do I get and pass the JSESSIONID into another method

Tags: java, servlets, jsessionid

To begin I am a bit new to java.
I have a web application I have been assigned to work on. It collects various user inputs via form and sends them via an a4j commandButton to a method in my jar folder. The method uses the form data to construct a web service client call. Part of the requirement is that I pass, as an element in the web service call, the current JSESSIONID from the request.

Steps I have taken:

In the class that contains the method I am calling I have set up getters and setters (outside of the helper class below).
I have added a helper class to my class as follows:

```
class GetSessionId extends HttpServlet {
    private String sessionid;
    public void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        sessionid = session.getId();
     }
     public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
     }
     public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
     }
     public String getSessionId(){
        return sessionid;
     }
     public void setSessionId(String sessionid){
        this.sessionid=sessionid;
     }
}
```

When I need the get the sessionid I used:

```
GetSessionId session_ID = new GetSessionId();
String sessionid = session_ID.getSessionId();
String sessionId = sessionid;
System.out.println("show me = " + sessionId);
```

But in the console (testing on my localhost) sessionid is null.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You mean the *session* is null and you therefore get an NPE because your code doesn't check. Try getSession(true). You don't need an entire servlet for this. You can call request.getSession() from anywhere you have a request.

Comment: Took your advise added a bit. Given I am working with JSF it turned out to be: 
ExternalContext extCtx = facesContext.getExternalContext();
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) extCtx.getSession(true);
String sessionId = session.getId();